# Running multiple NextAuth applications on different ports - getting deuathed

Tags: jwt, token, next.js13, next-auth

I am running 3 applications on localhost:3000, localhost:3001 and localhost:3002. I can successfully log in to localhost:3001, but when I visit one of the other pages, I get an error:

```
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#jwt_session_error decryption operation failed {
  message: 'decryption operation failed',
  stack: 'JWEDecryptionFailed: decryption operation failed\n' +
    '    at gcmDecrypt (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/jose/dist/node/cjs/runtime/decrypt.js:68:15)\n' +
    '    at decrypt (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/jose/dist/node/cjs/runtime/decrypt.js:91:20)\n' +
    '    at flattenedDecrypt (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/jose/dist/node/cjs/jwe/flattened/decrypt.js:117:52)\n' +
    '    at async compactDecrypt (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/jose/dist/node/cjs/jwe/compact/decrypt.js:20:23)\n' +
    '    at async jwtDecrypt (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/jose/dist/node/cjs/jwt/decrypt.js:10:23)\n' +
    '    at async Object.decode (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/jwt/index.js:44:25)\n' +
    '    at async Object.session (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/session.js:25:34)\n' +
    '    at async AuthHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:161:37)\n' +
    '    at async NextAuthRouteHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:49:30)\n' +
    '    at async NextAuth._args$ (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:83:24)\n' +
    '    at async eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:253:37)',
  name: 'JWEDecryptionFailed'
}
```

And my session cookie is deleted from localhost:3001, deauthenticating me.

How can I run all these applications on the same machine without them trying to auth with each other's respective token?

EDIT: I changed sessionCookie name property, and set options to:

cookies: {
sessionToken: {
name: `product1-next-auth.session-token`,
options: {
httpOnly: true,
sameSite: 'lax',
path: '/',
secure: true
}
}
},

This seems to work for on the client side, as session exists. But in     middleware.ts both session and token keep returning null!

```
    const session = await getSession({ req })
    console.log("MIDSession: \n", session)
    const token = await getToken({ req })
    console.log("MIDToken: \n", token)
```